# Analyze stability of equilibria using Routh-Hurwitz conditions

Tags: differential-equations, homework, control-systems

For an assignment, I need to analyze the stability of a system very close to equilibrium, using "Routh-Hurwitz conditions". I have already obtained the characteristic equation of my system, but I do not know how to proceed further. The question is worded quite vaguely, but I suspect obtaining a Routh array is the goal here.

My system:

```
Df1 = D[r[t], t] == (g*w) - m*r[t] - b*r[t]*v[t];
Df2 = D[l[t], t] == (p*b*r[t]*-v[t]) - (m*l[t]) - a*l[t];
Df3 = D[e[t], t] == (1 - p)*(b*r[t]*v[t]) + (a*l[t]) - d*e[t];
Df4 = D[v[t], t] == pi*e[t] - s*v[t];
```

State equilibrium conditions, substitute equation for Epsilon (to define near-equilibrium conditions):

```
eql = Solve[{Df1[[2]] == 0, Df2[[2]] == 0, Df3[[2]] == 0, Df4[[2]] == 0} /. v[t] -> 0, {r[t], l[t], e[t]}] // First
varsubs = Thread[{v[t], r[t], l[t], e[t]} -> ({0, r[t], l[t], e[t]} + \[Epsilon] {\[Delta]v[t], \[Delta]r[t], \[Delta]l[t], \[Delta]e[t]} /. eql)]

devl = Series[Df2[[2]] /. varsubs, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] // Normal
deve = Series[Df3[[2]] /. varsubs, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] // Normal
devv = Series[Df4[[2]] /. varsubs, {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}] // Normal
```

Generate matrix of substituted solutions:

```
(M = D[{devv, deve, devl}, {{\[Delta]v[t], \[Delta]e[t], \[Delta]l[t]}}]) //Simplify // MatrixForm
```

Get characteristic function from matrix:

```
P1 = CharacteristicPolynomial[M, t]
```

Output of aforementioned commands:

[image: Output]

Can I analyze this polynomial directly in Mathematica, i.e. forming a Routh array? Some insights would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards.

Comment: Does it really need to be Routh-Hurwitz? I'll see if I can post my routine for this later... (should prolly also do Schur-Cohn and Jury at some point)

Comment: The general question is simply "mathematical analysis of stability near-equilibrium conditions", Routh-Hurwitz was added as a hint after pestering the TA, so any input you have would be great!

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. I'd be curious to see your routine if you have a chance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are "modified Routh-Hurwitz criteria" that work directly on the Jacobian matrix that I prefer and don't seem very well known ([Fuller 1968](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82622256.pdf)).  Here's a function I wrote that uses them for up to the 3x3 case, which is based on eqns. 12.21-12.23 from Fuller.

```
RouthHurwitzCriteria[a_?MatrixQ]:=Module[{c3},
  If[!SquareMatrixQ[a],Message[RouthHurwitzCriteria::nonsq];Return[a]];
  Which[
    Length[a]==1,
    Return[Piecewise[{{True,a[[1,1]]<0},{False,a[[1,1]]>0}},Indeterminate]],
    Length[a]==2,
    Return[Piecewise[{
      {True,Tr[a]<0&&Det[a]>0},{False,Tr[a]>0||Det[a]<0}},Indeterminate]],
    Length[a]==3,
    c3=Det[{
      {a[[1,1]]+a[[2,2]],a[[2,3]],-a[[1,3]]},
      {a[[3,2]],a[[1,1]]+a[[3,3]],a[[1,2]]},
      {-a[[3,1]],a[[2,1]],a[[2,2]]+a[[3,3]]}}];
    Return[Piecewise[{
      {True,Tr[a]<0&&Det[a]<0&&c3<0},
      {False,Tr[a]>0||Det[a]>0||c3>0}},Indeterminate]],
    Length[a]>3,
    Message[RouthHurwitzCriteria::toobig];Return[a]
  ]
];
```

A more direct way to find your Jacobian matrix may be

```
M = D[{Df2[[2]], Df3[[2]], Df4[[2]]}, {{l[t], e[t], v[t]}}]
```

Then

```
Simplify[RouthHurwitzCriteria[M /. eql]]
```

gives the stability criteria.

I'd be happy if someone could implement the results from Fuller for larger matrices, but it looks significantly uglier.

Fuller, A. T. 1968. [Conditions for a matrix to have only characteristic roots with negative real parts.](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-247X(68)90116-9) Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 23: 71–98.

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks very promising and pretty neat. Do you mind if I use your solution, with credit?

Comment: No prob, that's the point of the site :)